# Choosing a test

Tags: categorical-data, binary-data

Let's say you run a restaurant and you want to work out which ingredients result in the best feedback (unhappy, neutral, happy, somewhat unhappy, somewhat happy) of the restaurant. Your data might look like this:

| Recipe | Feedback | Apples | Sugar | Beef | Egg | Sauce |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Omelette | Happy | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| Apple pie | Unhappy | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| Nachos | Neutral | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| Fish pie | Unhappy | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| ... |  |  |  |  |  |  |

The questions I want to answer are along the lines of:
'We can say with 76% confidence that beef will have a happy rating'
or 'dishes with egg have a 26% higher chance of being unhappy than dishes with apple'

Is there a relevant test for data in this format (perhaps logistic regression?) or would it be better off determining the counts of each feedback per ingredient and doing a different approach?

| Feedback | Tomato | Apples | Sugar | Beef | Egg | Sauce |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Happy | 5 | 7 | 11 | 1 | 0 | 3 |
| Unhappy | 1 | 1 | 4 | 0 | 0 | 4 |
| Neutral | 2 | 6 | 1 | 11 | 1 | 7 |
| Unhappy | 2 | 0 | 0 | 19 | 0 | 1 |
| ... |  |  |  |  |  |  |

Comment: Please add the [tag:self-study] tag & read its 
[wiki](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info). Then tell us what you understand thus far, what 
you've tried & where you're stuck. We'll provide hints to 
help you get unstuck. Please make these changes as just 
posting your homework & hoping someone will do it for you 
is grounds for closing.

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen this is not homework and is a self interest project for someone who has not done statistics in four years who no longer has access to their university coursework to look it up

Comment: Your question sounds as if you don't need a test but can address this by just estimating the probabilities by counting - except the "we are 76% confident" bit, but this in my view is bad wording anyway, although I know it appears in some textbooks and teaching material. You can say "beef has a happy rating in 76% of cases". Why isn't this enough?  A test would address a quite different question from those you have raised.